# Toyota Sienna 1999 - Valve Stem seals

Tags: toyota, valve, smoke

I've got a 1999 Toyota Sienna handed down to me from my family.

For the past year, on startup a heavy plume of blue smoke would come out. Researching online, I've read it's related to valve stem seals or piston rings. It's been checked out by mechanics who didn't necessarily say it's due to valve stem seals but that there's serious oil leakage, but it's not worth it to fix since this car is old and not worth that much anymore.

I've been able to live with this, but recently the smoking has gotten very intense, it will smoke on start up heavily and continue for a couple of minutes. Driving wise I don't notice anything, it's just really embarassing.

I've read online fixing these can cost up to $1000 dollars Canadian. Is this true? I'm hesistant on bringing mine in and getting charged $100 for a diagnostic test, then to find out it's super expensive, so I'm asking here instead. To me, it'd be worth it to fix if it's less than $500 Canadian.

Comment: It’ll be expensive, book time is 13.5 hrs plus .2 per valve. You’d need new gaskets, timing belt, etc...

Comment: If the rest of the vehicle is in good shape, you might consider getting a JDM engine replacement for it ... I don't personally know which engine went into your Sienna, but complete used JDM engines are a lot cheaper than getting a lot of work done on an engine. Might be worth it to take a look and see.

Comment: Looking online, JDM engines for a '99 sienna looks ~1k Canadian, that's just the engine...

Comment: @Ben, sounds like it'll take a lot of labor hours which I understand is the most expensive part. No way this repair goes under 1k Canadian?

Comment: @reoo2 probably not. I’d be wary of anyone who quotes under that.